# Obtener un valor en cocnreto en Firebase database realtime

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase, ionic, typescript

Quiero obtener el valor marcado en rojo en la imagen

[image: Dato]

De momento si tiro por consola lo siguiente, puedo ver que hay un nodo que se llama piece, y ahi dentro esta lo que quiero obtener, mas no se como accederlo.

```
    console.log(this.afDB.database.ref('Aula/' + 'Len8A'+ "/Asignatura"));
```

Gracias por la ayuda. Slds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he dado con la solución. La dejo aquí, se que a mas de alguno le servirá.
Buscando posibles problemas similares pero en ingles, di con muchos sitios que hacían reverencia a los snapshots. Así que me dirigí a la documentación oficial, con varios ejemplos ilustrativos: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

El código quedaría de la sgt manera:

```
// Test for the existence of certain keys within a DataSnapshot
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('Aula/');
  ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      var aula = snapshot.child(codigo).val(); // {Asignatura:"lenguaje",Curso:"8A"} Esta linea me devuelve un objeto con todos los valores de ese child
      var asignatura = snapshot.child(codigo + "/Asignatura").val(); // "Lenguaje"
      var curso = snapshot.child(codigo).child("Curso").val(); // "8A"
      console.log(aula);
      console.log(asignatura);
      console.log(curso);
    });
```